# How to get screen height and width in C

Tags: c, xorg, xserver

I get this following code.

```
typedef struct _display {
int fd;         /* Network socket. */
Window root;        /* Root window id. */
int vnumber;        /* X protocol version number. */
int dtype;      /* X server display device type. */
int dplanes;        /* Number of display bit planes. */
int dcells;     /* Number of display color map cells. */
_QEvent *head, *tail;   /* Input event queue. */
int qlen;       /* Length of input event queue */
int request;        /* Id of last request. */
char * lastdraw;    /* Last draw request. */
char *buffer;       /* Output buffer starting address. */
char *bufptr;       /* Output buffer index pointer. */
char *bufmax;       /* Output buffer maximum+1 address. */
int squish;     /* Squish MouseMoved events? */
Pixmap black, white;    /* Constant tile pixmaps */
char *displayname;  /* "host:display" string used on this connect*/
int width, height;  /* width and height of display */
} Display;
```

But what I don't get, is where X gets the width and height of the monitor. Would anyone happen to know the answer, or be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks, Arch

Comment: In the last line are two attributes: width and height of the display. Is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting screen size

- [linux](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=86911)
- [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So it parses Xrandr for the screen size?

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for that pointer (haha, get it? I made a programming reference...) I get it now!

Comment: @Archxiao the Display-wide "screen size" makes no sense, so you'd better avoid relying on these values for anything. BTW, where did you get such a header? I have another definition here (libx11 1.5.0), with no width and height. (BTW, it's legitimate for different Xlib implementation to have entirely different internal structures).

Comment: I got mine from the earlier version of XServer (X.V10R3).

Comment: The linux answer is gone. ;) :/

Answer (score 5):

Why not get root window's attributes?

```
XWindowAttributes ra;
XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), &ra);
w = ra.width;
h = ra.height;
```

Comment: Where did you get 'dsp' from?